# Do While statement not progressing to second result set in laravel using PDO

Tags: pdo, laravel, do-while

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets.  The results contain stats for a player, each result represents a year in which we have stats for him.

Stored procedure return from mysql CLI:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------+
| compperc | passyards | passtds | ints |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+
|     61.4 |       319 |       2 |    1 |
|     85.7 |        76 |       0 |    0 |
|     20.0 |         9 |       0 |    1 |
|     57.1 |        30 |       0 |    0 |
|    100.0 |        59 |       1 |    0 |
|     66.7 |        21 |       0 |    0 |
|     50.0 |        86 |       1 |    0 |
|     60.0 |        38 |       0 |    0 |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------+-----------+---------+------+
| compperc | passyards | passtds | ints |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+
|     80.0 |        40 |       0 |    0 |
|      0.0 |         0 |       0 |    0 |
|    100.0 |        40 |       0 |    0 |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using Laravel 4.1.2 and call the procedure in my Player Model with a raw PDO prepared statement:

```
$statDB = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
$statDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true); 
$results = $statDB->prepare("CALL fullstats(:id);");
$results->execute(array(':id'=> $id));
```

The previous block of code pulls in the proper result sets (manually iterating using 
`if($statDB->nextRowset()) { $statArr[] = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); }` works) but when I try to iterate through it using a do-while statement it never gets to the second result set.

```
$statArr = array();
do 
{
    $statArr[] = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} while ($results->nextRowset());
```

I can add `dd($statArr);` immediately after I set the initial `$statArr[]` and it will return the set of stats for the first year.  I can also add `dd($results->nextRowset());` after I set the `$statArr[]` and it `returns true` so it theoretically should move through the additional result sets.  If I let the statement execute I get a generic error from Laravel: `PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`.  It provides no additional details as to what's going wrong.  I've tried the same do-while statement in a raw php file (on a different domain but the same server) using PDO and it works without a problem.

Is there some configuration option that I need to set to get this to work?  I've been beating my head against the problem for an entire day and can't figure out why this isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update:
The `PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` is coming from the second `$statArr[] = $results->fetchAll();` so it's entering the second result set, it just won't fetch the data.  I also removed the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` from `fetchAll()` as I've read it doesn't work properly but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in the PDO/mysql driver.  The `nextRowset()` method doesn't return false when it's out of rowsets so the fetch statement tries to access data that isn't there.  This causes the nondescript general error on the `fetchall()` method and in turn breaks the script.

The PHP bug report:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62820

Since the `nextRowset()` method wasn't working properly I added a build query that gives me the count of the results I should expect and then have a counter in the loop with an if statement that breaks the loop if the loop count is equal to the count returned by the query.

Here's the working function:

```
public function allstats($id) {
    $statDB = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();

    $statDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
    $years = $statDB->prepare('select count(distinct year) from pass_stats where player_id = :id');
    $years->execute(array(':id'=> $id));
    $years = (int) $years->fetchColumn();

    $results = $statDB->prepare("CALL fullstats(:id);");
    $results->execute(array(':id'=> $id));

    $statArr = array();
    $i = 1; // Set to one to mimic sql count

    do
    {

        if($i === $years) { break; }
        foreach($results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $g) {

            $statArr[$g['year']][] = $g;
        }

        $i++; 
    }  while ($results->nextRowset()); // Check for next rowset

    return $statArr;
}
```